# External drive no longer recognised in any way

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, connection

I have an external drive Samsung M3, 500GB. All of a sudden, it won't get recognized, and I tried everything - from switching the connection cable, trying different PC, to command line and professional diagnostic tools. There is no sign of the plugged in drive on the PC, even though the drive itself is making a noise from rotation when plugged in. There is also no light blinking. It might have happened after unplugging it without first safely unmounting it, but I'm not sure though.

Is there anything I can do, or do I need to take it to a repair service?

EDIT: The blue light is also not working, and I think it was before.

Comment: I had a Seagate drive do the same thing and (sadly) I was not able to recover anything from it, even using a local recovery company. I suggest you investigate a local company

Comment: And what was the reason?

Comment: The drive had failed beyond recovery. That is why I suggest you contact a recovery company to see if they can help

Comment: What is the last thing you did with your  drive? How old it is?

Comment: It's only few months old, less than half a year. It was used only for backups, so it was used only few times. the last thing I did was copying some pictures to it. Then, after finishing it, I unplugged it (not sure if safely, as stated before).

Comment: Do you run any antivirus software? How do you normally 'safely unmount' it? Was it just formatted as NTFS? or something more exotic for a PC like exfat etc?

Comment: I think it was NTFS, since it was working out of the box - whichever format it shipped with, basically. I press the dedicated unmount botton. I was on a Linux machine when it stopped working, so no, no antiviruses.

Comment: Have tried Linux commands like dmesg (see the outputs as drive is connected) ;fdisk -l ; lsscsi; lsblk -f ;

Comment: Yes, there is no indication of the external drive. Also see my edit.

Comment: Found a link stating problems which sound similar but not sure so follow the guide at your own risk : https://www.instructables.com/id/Samsung-M3-Portable-HDD-REPAIR/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the external HDD to a repair service, and the problem was in the external case - it seems the drive fell at some point and some cable pins disconnected, i.e. the power pins were still connected, but the pins necessary for data transfer were not (at least not all of them). They've put it in another case just in case (pun intended), and it now works as it should.